# PHP - Iterable Object Issue

Tags: php, mongodb, object, elasticsearch

I am working on a site in which our system administrators can select whether to select to retrieve our data from either mongodb or elasticsearch. I can setup both fine, but I want to setup a switch case that will select the correct document retrieval system based on a preference in the sites admin section. When mongo returns a stdClass object I can iterate through the object to print each item using something like the following:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

I can then then retrieve the total number of returned items using $items->count(). However, when using elasticsearch I am returned an object in which I need to go:

```
foreach($items['hits']['hits'] as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

The count can be retrieved using $items['hits']['total']. If I extract the array of items (let's call it "$finalitems" and the count (let's call it $count) from the elasticsearch returned data, how can I convert this to a stdClass object like what mongo returns so that I can iterate directly through the class to get the value of each item, as well as calling a method count() which will retrieve the count? I want to do this so that I can easily switch between the two data objects without having to have completely separate functions handling the same task.

Comment: whats the output of `print_r($items);` in second case? If you are getting an object returned then array notation like that wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend converting `ElasticSearch` result to `MongoDB` result (or vice-versa) for multiple reasons. One is that even though now it will feel like it makes it easier if you have them both as same object, in the future as more fields might need to be used/manipulated it might become a nightmare.

One solution is that you create a new class, say `DocumentItem`, and convert both the `MongoDB` AND `ElasticSearch` results into this class. This way, the part of your code that manipulates, iterates, does other operations on the return value of both `MongoDB` and `ElasticSearch` will work on a `DocumentItem` object, using its defined methods.

And you will have two conversion functions for translating `MongoDB` & `ElasticSearch` return values to this object. In the future if a new field needs to be added, you will need to update the conversion functions accordingly. And if a new Document Server is added,you only need to write the conversion function, since the `DocumentItem` class is already well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think that you make a good point here and I'll try to go this route.

Comment: @user2694306 - glad to help, if you run into trouble while creating your conversion functions, Im sure there are many folks in SO to help! You should first define how the DocumentItem class should look like, what functions/variables it needs and then start writing the conversion functions to meet that goal. Best of luck!